# Given measurable mapping $T$, to show that a random variable is measurable with respect to $\sigma(T)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am currently learning probability theory using the textbook A Probability Path by Resnick. I'm running into trouble with the following problem: (chapter 3, Q 19)

Suppose $T : (\Omega_{1}, \mathcal{B}_{1}) \rightarrow (\Omega_{2}, \mathcal{B}_{2})$ is a measurable mapping and $X$ is a random variable on $\Omega_{1}$. Show $X \in \sigma(T)$ iff there is a random variable $Y$ on $(\Omega_{2}, \mathcal{B}_{2})$ such that
$X(\omega_{1}) =Y(T(\omega_{1})), \forall \omega_{1} \in \Omega_{1} $

I've done the if part and am having problems with the only if part. Any help/hints would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The statement is known as [factorization lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_lemma). There are plenty of questions on this result here on stackexchange; so please give it a go and use the search.

Comment: Thank you. After some searching I found the solution here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130948/converse-to-composition-of-measurable-functions-is-measurable